# Write-Back cache in Java, when to write back

Tags: java, caching

Wondering when a write-back should be performed? I thought it was when you're writing to an address, that isn't in the cache already. So if there is something in that slot, that has a valid Dirty Bit, then you'd want to copy that back to its place in main_mem, so you don't lose the data.

But what about when you want to read a different address (this is a direct-mapped cache)?

So do you perform a write-back everytime there is a cache miss and a dirty bit (Regardless of read or write)?

Comment: you don't really have a choice, do you?  if you have to drop something from the cache and it is dirty, you have to write it.  it doesn't really matter _why_ you are dropping it from the cache.

Comment: I wasn't really asking why. but i supposed i answered by own question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that when a cache line needs to be re-used for any reason, if its dirty it needs to be written out (possibly to a lower cache or main memory)